# install tweepy python no command supplied

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to install the libraries of tweepy in python 2.7.
when I start the setup.py I get an error:

error: no command supplied

how can I do? I've just installed the libraries setuptools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally want to use a tool like `pip` or `easy_install` to handle the installation of packages for you.

The `setup.py` script takes commands; it can do different things for you, including installing in you Python site-packages location, but you do need to tell it *what* command to execute.

To see the available commands, use:

```
setup.py --help-commands
```

but for installing, you probably wanted:

```
setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python setup.py install
```

You may need first also do:

```
python setup.py build
```

and if you are on linux probable both will need to be prefixed by `sudo`

easy_install or pip will do the above for you and will also fetch any dependencies.